# Which confidence interval should I use to bound actual values around a predicted value?

Tags: confidence-interval, predictive-models, prediction-interval

I have a 'black box' model that outputs model predictions, but I don't know what actually goes on inside the model.  I also have a bunch of data that I can pass through the model so that I can compare the predictions with actual results.  Which interval would I use to bound most of the actual values around the predicted value?  I don't think that I would use the prediction interval because that would give me a range that the next prediction is likely to be in, correct?  I would like to say that for a single prediction, I am 95% confident that the actual value falls into this interval.

Comment: Sounds like you might be able to do some sort of bootstrap. @Whuber might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelLew.. any thoughts @whuber?  Could I use RMSD to calculate the interval?